# Jenkins Failed to Connect to Repository

Tags: jenkins, ssh, bitbucket

I am trying to connect Jenkins to a private BitBucket repository.

I have a set (both id_rsa and id_rsa.pub) of SSH keys generated at `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh`. I've copied the `id_rsa.pub` key and pasted it in the deploy keys section of my BitBucket repository. Similarly, running the command `git ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:user/project.git` has a valid return and has been added to `known_hosts`.

What might be causing my Jenkins to not connect in the git Source Code Management section of Jenkins? The error returned is:

> Failed to connect to repository : Command "git -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h https://git@bitbucket.org/user/project.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
>   stdout: 
>   stderr: remote: Invalid username or password. If you log in via a third party service you must ensure you have an account password set in your account profile.
>   fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git@bitbucket.org/user/project.git/'

I also tried `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org` as per [**this doc**](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/troubleshoot-ssh-issues-271943403.html) from Atlassian regarding troubleshooting SSH issues. The return states at that:

> This deploy key has read access to the following repositories:
>
> user/project: Jenkins -- jenkins@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx

Comment: So I made a dumb mistake and used `https://git@bitbucket.org/user/project.git` for Repository URL instead of `git@bitbucket.org:user/project.git` *facepalm* Changing it to the latter works, without the need for filling out credentials (assuming SSH has been set up successfully).

Comment: Please, add your comment as solution and mark this as solved :)

Comment: you ought to add this as the anser @Xenyal . I made the same mistake with GitHub.

Comment: JoSSI and @angryip Thanks for bringing this up. I've added it as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the Project Repository field that Jenkins' [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-ProjectConfiguration) provides, it seems that one of their examples shown in their home page for that field (specifically, `https://git@bitbucket.org/user/project.git`) does not work. It might either be a case of plugin version, or how BitBucket might be configured differently than GitHub, of which their documentation uses for examples.

What did work for me however, was using the git address of the following format:

```
git@bitbucket.org:user/project.git
```